# javascript iterator suggestion

Tags: javascript, iterator

I have writen this function to iterate over arrays and I am looking for better opinions.
Thanks in advance.

```
var arrayIndexer = function (arr) {
    var index = 0;
        return {
            getNext: function(){ 
                index = index + 1
                return arr[index - 1];
            },
            hasNext: function(){ 
                return arr[index] !== undefined;
            }
        };  
};


var colorIndexer = arrayIndexer(["red","green","blue","orange","purple"]);

while(colorIndexer.hasNext()){
    console.log(colorIndexer.getNext());
}
```

Comment: If there is a problem with the code, you need to describe the problem clearly. If this code works fine as is, and you're just looking for improvements, it really should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: @Pointy That's a method of iterating, not an "iterator".

Comment: FWIW, `arr[index] !== undefined` may be broken, depending upon intent. Consider `[1, undefined, 3]`. Why not just check the length?

Comment: What's wrong with `for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {...}` ?

Comment: @PM77-1 A basic loop - like forEach - doesn't allowed delayed iteration or lazy fetching.

Comment: @user2864740 fine, but one wonders what the point of an iterator might be given that `.forEach()` exists.

Comment: @Pointy See my [new] comment to PM77-1.

Comment: @user2864740 how exactly does this code allow for "delayed iteration" or "lazy fetching"?

Comment: @Pointy My arguments are for an Iterator - and forEach not being a replacement. An Iterator over an Array could be switched with something from not-an-array; forEach cannot in the same manner. My point is *the question is about an Iterator*.

Comment: "switched with something from not-an-array" ... what does that mean? And all (or most) of the Array prototype operators can be used with non-array objects that act like arrays, like `arguments` or NodeList instances.

Comment: It means that an Array-Iterator could be replaced with an iterator over a different source - *keeping the advantages of Iterators*. The OP is asking for an Iterator.

Comment: @user2864740 you are right checking the length is better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cool trick I rarely see used - the [Yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) keyword!

Probably overkill for what your doing (whatever that may be), but if your looking for opinions, tips, or other options, this is something that might be worth exploring. Happy Coding!

Comment: This is an upcoming ES6 proposal.